# Making a resizeable bordered RelativeLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I seem to be having some trouble trying to come up with a way to make a resizable layout. At least that's what I think it's called.

I am working on a larger game project and I need to create a "Dialogue Box" for the game. I need to call this class in the file `dialogue` and create it like this:

`dialogue_window = Dialogue(pos=(x, y), size=(x, y))`

Now I also have some image files named `x_border` and `y_border` which I want to stretch to fit the y and x sizes. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Main(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, size, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.y_border = './assets/y_border.png'
        self.x_border = './assets/x_border.png'
        self.dialogue_left_border = None
        self.dialogue_right_border = None
        self.dialogue_top_border = None
        self.dialogue_background = None
        self.dialogue_bottom_border = None
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos

        self.make_dialogue()

    def make_dialogue(self):
        self.dialogue_frame = RelativeLayout(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.dialogue_background = Image(source="./assets/dialogue_background.png",
                                         size=self.size,
                                         pos=self.pos)

        self.dialogue_left_border = Image(source=self.y_border,
                                          size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_right_border = Image(source=self.y_border,
                                           size=(16, self.size.y))

        self.dialogue_top_border = Image(source=self.x_border,
                                         size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_bottom_border = Image(source=self.x_border,
                                         size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_background)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_left_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_right_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_top_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_bottom_border)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Dialogue"
        return Main((300, 500), (500, 500))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/marssim/MarsSim/mars_dialogue.py", line 65, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/marssim/MarsSim/mars_dialogue.py", line 61, in build
     return Main((300, 500), (500, 500))
   File "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/marssim/MarsSim/mars_dialogue.py", line 29, in __init__
     self.make_dialogue()
   File "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/marssim/MarsSim/mars_dialogue.py", line 39, in make_dialogue
     size=(self.size.x, 16))
 AttributeError: 'ObservableReferenceList' object has no attribute 'x'
Exception ignored in: functools.partial(<function _widget_destructor at 0x10061fbf8>, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 265, in _widget_destructor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 742, in unbind_widget
  File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'weakref' object has no attribute 'cline_in_traceback'
Exception ignored in: functools.partial(<function _widget_destructor at 0x10061fbf8>, 22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 265, in _widget_destructor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 742, in unbind_widget
  File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'weakref' object has no attribute 'cline_in_traceback'
Exception ignored in: functools.partial(<function _widget_destructor at 0x10061fbf8>, 15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 265, in _widget_destructor
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 742, in unbind_widget
  File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'weakref' object has no attribute 'cline_in_traceback'
```

Which I think is because of 61 `return Main((300, 500), (500, 500))` but I don't know of any way to fix this. I've done a bit of searching yet I couldn't find anything that helps me.

I also think for the overall goal I need to make the border's stretch attribute to be true for it to be able to stretch around. I have not placed these widgets yet because of the error not letting me see exactly where I want to

Answer (score 0):

Please in your `make_dialogue` method replace all the `self.size.x` and `self.size.y` by `self.size[0]` and `self.size[1]` respectively I don't know if this will solve your problem but It will solve the traceback error

*update*: Instead of initialize your images with `None` update them all with `ObjectProperty(None)` import `ObjetProperty` with `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`

Comment: Thank you that works, but it still just appears as black screen without any of the widgets I've added to the layout.. I even did `self.add_widget(self.dialogue_frame)` and no change it still is black

Comment: @MaxBethke I guess the problem is the relative positions and sizes of your widgets in your relativelayout I have tried your code but with FloatLayout instead of RelativeLayout and it worked,try to replace the 2 RelativeLayout by FloatLayout or check the relative pos and sizes of your Images

Answer (score 0):

## Black Window

The black window was due to pos=(500, 500) and size=(300, 500). The size of the window is (800, 600) i.e. width=800, and height=600. I have made the following changes for illustration and used other images. Please refer to example and output for details.

### build method

Replace:

```
return Main(size=(300, 500), pos=(500, 500))
```

with:

```
return Main(size=(300, 500), pos=(0, 0))
```

### make_dialogue method

Add the following as the last line :

```
self.add_widget(self.dialogue_frame)
```

## Error - Fixes

The solution is to replace the following as shown below.

## __init__ method

Replace:

```
def __init__(self, size, pos):
    super().__init__()
```

with:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

## Parameters pos & size

Replace:

```
self.size = size
self.pos = pos
```

with:

```
self.size = kwargs.get('size')
self.pos = kwargs.get('pos')
self.size.x = self.size[0]
self.size.y = self.size[1]
self.pos.x = self.pos[0]
self.pos.y = self.pos[1]
```

## build method

Replace:

```
return Main((300, 500), (500, 500))
```

with:

```
return Main(size=(300, 500), pos=(500, 500))
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Main(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y_border = './assets/y_border.png'
        self.x_border = './assets/x_border.png'
        self.dialogue_left_border = None
        self.dialogue_right_border = None
        self.dialogue_top_border = None
        self.dialogue_background = None
        self.dialogue_bottom_border = None
        self.size = kwargs.get('size')
        self.pos = kwargs.get('pos')
        self.size.x = self.size[0]
        self.size.y = self.size[1]
        self.pos.x = self.pos[0]
        self.pos.y = self.pos[1]

        self.make_dialogue()

    def make_dialogue(self):
        self.dialogue_frame = RelativeLayout(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.dialogue_background = Image(source="./assets/dialogue_background.png",
                                         size=self.size,
                                         pos=self.pos)

        self.dialogue_left_border = Image(source=self.y_border,
                                          size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_right_border = Image(source=self.y_border,
                                           size=(16, self.size.y))

        self.dialogue_top_border = Image(source=self.x_border,
                                         size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_bottom_border = Image(source=self.x_border,
                                         size=(self.size.x, 16))

        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_background)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_left_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_right_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_top_border)
        self.dialogue_frame.add_widget(self.dialogue_bottom_border)
        self.add_widget(self.dialogue_frame)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Dialogue"
        return Main(size=(300, 500), pos=(0, 0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - Dialogue]

Comment: Doing what you have said to do, my kivy window still appears back? I added the dialogue frame to the self via `self.add_widget(self.dialogue_frame)` what is going wrong here?

Comment: And no, I do not want a pop-up as I want the player to be able to interact with other objects while the dialogue is up (tutorial-like)

Comment: I have updated my post for resolving the black window.